# Как сделать таймер, после истечения которого закрывается программа?

Tags: python, datetime, таймер

Хотел бы реализовать таймер, который ждёт следующей команды и если команда не будет вызвана в течении заданного времени, программа закрывается.
Приведу пример:
Программа после нажатия на кнопку **старт** (кнопка **старт** является примером, в программе не используется графический фреймворк).
Я хочу донести то, что программа после любого действия (допустим, вызов n функции) запускает таймер на х секунд и ждёт следующей команды.
После того как таймер истекает, программа закрывается. Заранее всем спасибо за Вашу помощь!!!

Comment: Ок, каким образом и что за команду ждет программа? Это сигнал операционной системы?

Answer (score 3):

На псевдокоде будет как-то так:

```
функция:
    ждём какое-то время
    закрываем программу

запускаем поток для выполнения функции
ждём ввод
принудительно завершаем поток
```

Если успели что-то ввести, то поток будет завершён и программа не закроется. Иначе сработает закрытие программы в потоке.